# std::ofstream::open will it read the entire file into memory?

Tags: c++, memory, fstream

I'm writing things from my memory to the disk in order to free my memory.

I wonder each time I call open(), and appendix new elements to the end of the file, will it read the entire file into memory? or it is just a pointer to the end of the file?

Comment: I don't understand; how can open and append perform a read?

Comment: You should open the file with `ate` to get a pointer to the end.

Comment: I think strictly an implementation *could* do that. But it won't

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't need read, I need write.....

Comment: @0x499602D2 so if I use ate, will it read the entire file into the memory before I write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fstream` implementation doesn't specify exactly what happens if you use the `ofstream::app`, `ios::app`, `ofstream::ate` or `ios::ate` mode to open the file.

But in any sane implementation, the file is not read into memory, all that happens is that the `fstream` implementation positions the "current position" to the end of the file.

To read the entire file into memoiry would be rather terrible if you have a system with 2GB of RAM and you wanted to append to a file that is bigger than 2GB.

Being very pedantic, when writing something to a text-file, it is likely that the filesystem that is part of the operating system will read the last few (kilo)bytes of the file, as most hard-disks and similar storage requires that the data is being written to a "block", which is a fixed size (e.g. 512 bytes or 4 kilobytes). So, unless the current filesize is exactly at a boundary of such a block, the filesystem must read the last block of the file and write it back with the additional data that you asked to write.

If you are worried about appending to a log-file that gets very large, no, it's not an issue. If you are worried about memory safety because your file has secret data that you won't want stored in memory, then may be a problem, because a portion of that will probably be loaded into memory, and there is nothing you can do to control that.

Comment: So if I use open without ate, will it read in the entire file to the memory ? or it will just read in the first pointer?

Comment: In effect, it will not read the file at all. I will edit to make clearer.

Comment: As others already stated: `open()` won't read anything into memory.